# Корректна ли постановка знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

*"Осень теплая и приветливая стояла за окном".*

В данном случае нет поводов обособлять слова *"теплая и приветливая"*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Обособленные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108) (Розенталь, § 18, п. 6)

> При отсутствии предшествующего определения последующие одиночные определения обособляются или не обособляются в зависимости от степени их интонационно-смысловой близости с определяемым существительным. Ср.:
>
> *В воздухе, **знойном и пыльном**, тысячеголосый говор* (М. Г.); *Мать, **грустная и тревожная**, сидела на толстом узле и плакала* (Гл.) — в этих примерах существительное не нуждается в обязательном определении (связь между ними слабая); 
>   *Вместо весёлой петербургской жизни, ожидала меня скука в стороне **глухой и отдалённой*** (П.); *Под этой толстой серой шинелью билось сердце **страстное и благородное*** (Л.) — в этих примерах существительное нуждается в определении, без него высказывание не имеет законченного смысла.

Если из представленного в вопросе предложения убрать определения, то оно не потеряет смысл: *Осень стояла за окном*. Поэтому постановка запятых представляется здесь уместной, интонационно оправданной:

*Осень, теплая и приветливая, стояла за окном*.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Если из представленного в вопросе предложения убрать 
  определения, то оно не потеряет смысл: Осень стояла за окном.
```

Странное, искусственно выхолощенное предложение. Какой Вы там нашли смысл? Не хочется думать, что есть такие художники слова, которые хотят нас удивить образом **стоящей за окном** осени. А где ж ей ещё стоять? У стола? У ворот? В поле?  Если б у стола, то да, удивили бы абсурдностью. А за окном - указание на существование, бытие  осени вообще. Главное-то значение предложения не в том, что она стоит где-то, а в том, что она теплая и приветливая, а это означает, что **построение предложения неправильное**. Видимо, следовало бы построить так: "*За окном стояла осень  - теплая и приветливая ".* Возможна и запятая вместо тире.

Или так: Осень стояла за окном  теплая и приветливая.

Если уж оставить этот неудачный порядок слов, то хоть **запятые не надо ставить**, чтоб  намёк остался на главенство признака, а не действия **стояла:** **Осень теплая и приветливая** стояла за окном". Тогда будет видимость составного именного сказуемого **стояла тёплая и приветливая**, а не простого глагольного **стояла**.

А вообще, это, видимо, авторы какого-то пособия испортили хороший образ писателя В.Чивилихина:

Первая моя московская осень, тёплая и приветливая, стояла долго (В. Чивилихин).

Вот сократили, заменили одно слово - и получилась пустышка.

Comment: Людмила, полностью с Вами согласен. Интуитивно чувствовал,  что что-то здесь не так. А под "не потеряет смысл" я имел в виду формальную грамматическую правильность. Спасибо.

Comment: Хотя всё-таки, если сделать сильное ударение (эмоциональный акцент) на "Осень", а "стояла за окном" произнести, грубо говоря,  шёпотом, то, кажется, и такое предложение имеет право на существование...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ну да, имеет право быть,  нельзя отказывать ему в таком праве. Можно даже без шёпота обойтись, например:  "Но прекрасное, наполненное счастьем лето  всё-таки однажды  кончилось. Осень //стояла за окном". Логическим ударением выделена "осень".

Comment: @Sharon  Спасибо! Я уже и забыл про этот вопрос.